# Show that $f^{-1}\{f(a)\}=a\text{Ker}f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

> Let $G,G'$ be groups and assume $f: \space G \longrightarrow G'$ is a
>   **homomorphism**. Show that $\forall f(a) \in \ \operatorname{Im}f$: $$
>  f^{-1}\{f(a)\}=a \operatorname{Ker}f $$

To begin with, the kernel of the homomorphism is a **normal subgroup** of $G$, $ \operatorname{Ker}f \triangleleft G.$ This implies that the left and right cosets coincide. Thus, the **set of cosets** of $ \operatorname{Ker} f$ is:
$$
G/ \operatorname{ker}f:=\left\{ a \operatorname{Ker}f, \space \forall a \in G \right\}
$$
Now, since $ \operatorname{ker}f \triangleleft G$, $G/ \operatorname{Ker}f$ is a group. Moreover, the **fundamental theorem of homomorphisms** gives:
$$
G/ \operatorname{Ker}f \cong  \operatorname{Im}f
$$
and so there exists a bijection $\varphi: \space G/ \operatorname{Ker}f \longrightarrow  \operatorname{Im}f\;$ s.t. 
$$
\varphi(a \operatorname{Ker}f)= \operatorname{Im}f, \space \forall a \in G
$$
Given that, we must show:
$$
f^{-1}[\varphi(a \operatorname{Ker}f)]=a \operatorname{Ker}f 
$$

---

**Question:**

Which argument about the relation of $f$ and $\varphi$ should one use to prove the initial statement?

Comment: Are you imposed to use all this *armada* of theorems? I mean a direct proof of $f^{-1}\{f(a)\}=a\text{Ker}f$ is quite simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're overthinking the problem.

Just prove that $f(b)=f(a)$ iff $b=ak$ with $k \in \ker f$.

Comment: Indeed, I overcomplicated this. Simple proof: $f(ak)=f(a) \cdot f(k)=f(a) \cdot e'=f(a)$

Comment: @Jevaut, yes, that's one side. But the other side is equally easy.